# Return a user that is not the following step, but was in the first

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following sample dataset that was the result of a groupby where i grouped by Steps and CampaignSource. And return the grouped UserIds, in a Set

`df2=df[['CampaignSource','UserId','Steps']].groupby(['Steps','CampaignSource'],as_index=False).agg(lambda x: set(x))`

| Steps | CampaignSource | Set_UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Step-1" | "Apple" | "Jeff","John","Antonio","Jon" |
| "Step-1" | "Banana" | "Jeff","John","Antonio",Jon" |
| "Step-1" | "Potato" | "Jeff","John","Antonio",Jon" |
| "Step-2" | "Apple" | "Jeff","John" |
| "Step-2" | "Banana" | "Jeff","John","Antonio" |
| "Step-2" | "Potato" | "Jeff","John" |
| "Step-3" | "Apple" | "Jeff" |
| "Step-3" | "Banana" | "Jeff","John" |
| "Step-3" | "Potato" | "Jeff" |

Wanted end result

| Steps | CampaignSource | Set_UserId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Step-1" | "Apple" | "Antonio","Jon" |
| "Step-1" | "Banana" | "Jon" |
| "Step-1" | "Potato" | "Antonio","Jon" |
| "Step-2" | "Apple" | "John" |
| "Step-2" | "Banana" | "Antonio" |
| "Step-2" | "Potato" | "John" |

Basically as you can see by the sample and end result, i want to bring up the UserIds, that are in the first step but not in the second one. And after that, the ones who are in the second, but not in the third. This is basically a loss report that returns me the userid.
Here is my code, my attempt worked . But sincerely it lacks flexibility so i have been wanting. For some better ways, would appreciate some inputs

```
for i,z in enumerate(zip(df2['CampaignSource'],df2['UserId'])):
print(z[0])
if z[0] == 'Apple':
    if i == 0:
        k = i
    else:
        list_userid.append(df2['UserId'][k]-df2['UserId'][i])
        k = i
        
if z[0] == 'Banana':
    if i == 1:
        a = i
    else:
        list_userid.append(df2['UserId'][a]-df2['UserId'][i])
        a = i
        
if z[0] == 'Potato':
    if i == 2:
        b = i
    else:
        list_userid.append(df2['UserId'][b]-df2['UserId'][i])
        b = i
```

Comment: Please provide a constructor for your dataframe using `df2.head(10).to_dict()`

Comment: Here we go, is worth noting i could bring you know all the 'UserIds". values bcs of the amount of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame([item for sub in (list(df.groupby("CampaignSource").agg(lambda x: x).apply(lambda x: list(zip([x.name] * len(x["Steps"]), x["Steps"][:-1], [(list(set(s) - set(x["Set_UserId"][i+1]))) for i,s in enumerate(x["Set_UserId"][:-1])])), axis=1).to_dict().values())) for item in sub])
```

with a few complexity :))
if you want exactly that shape... if your desired can be in another shape, it can be simpler